How to configure a loader for leaflet images in Angular 17?
I'm a recent Angular user, and I have an Angular 17 project, with a leaflet map.
When I try to build the project, I have 3 errors with 3 images of the leaflet map (marker icon and layers): 
Does anyone know how to configure that loader or solve this error?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
